# Multiple entry in STL Order statistic tree

Tags: c++, stl, set

Is there a way to insert same entry in STL Order statistic tree ([PBDS](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/ext/pb_ds/))?
suppose i want to insert 12,12,30,40 in my tree. so the order of 12 is 0,30 is 2. now if i erase 12. the order of 12 should be still 0 but order of 30 is 1. is it supported?

Comment: What is a "STL Order statistic tree (PBD)"?

Comment: #include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
using namespace __gnu_pbds;
typedef tree<int,null_type,less<int>,rb_tree_tag,
tree_order_statistics_node_update> set_t;